# Vue DOM update doesn't happen in first click, works in subsequent clicks

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue app for a dynamic form that has two buttons and I need to send along in the request which one was clicked. I am doing this by updating the value of a hidden input field then submitting the form with jQuery. For some reason though the first time I click on the button that sets the hidden input to `true` it sends `false` initially but subsequent clicks will send the appropriate value.

Below is a small snippet of what I am essentially doing without the actual jQuery request. I can see the value is updated correctly so I am not sure if it is a race condition or if I am missing something obvious.

```
<form id="myVueForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="submitEdit" :value="submitEdit">
  <button type="button" @click="submitEdit = true">Submit Edit</button>
  <button type="button" @click="submitEdit = false">Submit without Edit</button>
</form>

var myApp = new Vue({
  el: '#myVueForm',
  data: function() {
    return {
      submitEdit: false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    'submitEdit': function(value) {
      console.log(this.submitEdit, "submitEdit value");
      console.log('Submitting form!');
    }
  }
})
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jvGXLG?editors=1111

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vue's updating mechanism is somehow asynchronous by nature. If you do something immediately after making changes to its virtual DOM, the immediate code executes first even before the update to Vue's DOM is applied. You have to use `.$nextTick()` in order to execute things AFTER the actual update (next tick) to the virtual DOM.

```
'submitEdit': function(value) {
   this.$nextTick(function(){
      console.log(this.submitEdit, "submitEdit value");
      console.log('Submitting form!');
   });
 }
```